# Full Simplify not cancelling terms, even with Assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I'm having a problem getting Mathematica in vanishing the following expression:

$\frac{-3 \:\sqrt{6}\: x \sqrt{\frac{y}{3 x-2 \sqrt{3}}}+ \:6 \sqrt{2} \: \sqrt{\frac{y}{3 x-2 \sqrt{3}}}+\: \sqrt{6}\: \sqrt{\left(3 x-2 \sqrt{3}\right) y}}{12
   \sqrt{\pi } \:x}$

When I plug it into Mathematica:

```
    FullSimplify[((
    6 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] - 
    3 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] + 
    Sqrt[6] Sqrt[(-2 Sqrt[3] + 3 x) y])/(12 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x))]
```

it obviously cannot cancel the terms since I have not specified what the forms x and y take (real, complex, positive etc.).

Now I **know** the result is zero for real values of $x>\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $y\neq0$. I can actually get Mathematica to give me these exact conditions by using Reduce:

```
    Reduce[{(6 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] - 
3 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] + 
Sqrt[6] Sqrt[(-2 Sqrt[3] + 3 x) y])/(12 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x) == 0, 
y > 0, x \[Element] Integers}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

I have added the condition $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ which then gives me the correct answer:

```
    x \[Element] Integers && x >= 2 && y > 0
```

Perfect! These are the conditions I need to specify to `FullSimplify`for the cancelling to occur. However, when I try

```
    FullSimplify[(
    6 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] - 
    3 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] + 
    Sqrt[6] Sqrt[(-2 Sqrt[3] + 3 x) y])/(12 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x), 
    x \[Element] Integers && x >= 2 && y > 0]
```

it still is not able to give me 0 as an answer, it just spits out the answer again. What exactly is happening here? I'm at my wits' end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the square roots not properly simplifying.
To avoid it, you can use `PowerExpand` to force Mathematica to consider numerator and denominator inside the square roots as separate:

```
expr = (6 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] - 
 3 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[-(y/(2 Sqrt[3] - 3 x))] + 
 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[(-2 Sqrt[3] + 3 x) y])/(12 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x);

FullSimplify[
 PowerExpand@expr,
 x \[Element] Integers && x >= 2 && y > 0
 ]
(* 0 *)
```

[image]

Comment: Why would `FullSimplify` not use `PowerExpand` in its procedure and why would `Reduce` be able to work this out but not `FullSimplify`?

Comment: @OldTomMorris hard to say. The heuristics used by `FullSimplify` to simplify expressions do not always give the results one would expect, which  is to be expected by such a complex function. After all, it may make sense to not expand certain expression to simplify. With `Reduce` you are specifically asking for conditions that make the expression zero, which is an entirely different (and much simpler under many points of view) kind of problem.

Comment: @OldTomMorris In general you should not expect functions like `FullSimplify` to just give you the result you want. They are "magic" black boxes that often just work, but lots of other times they need suggestions on the user part on the kind of result that is wanted. This is where more specific functions like `PowerExpand`, `Together`, `Expand` and so on come into play.

Comment: This is the thing though, I don't see what other conditions I would need for the terms to cancel. I guessed what conditions would be needed for the $x$ and $y$, I also used `Reduce` to double check and still no good for `Full Simplify`. There's got to be an explanation for this behaviour.